# ReferenceError: window is not defined, when trying to sync the search input state with react instant search

Tags: reactjs, url, next.js, react-instantsearch

I am using next js and I am trying to sync my search state with url query params, so that during navigation I don't lose my search input state.

I know that it's a sever side language, but what can I do to make this code work with window object?

This is a code snippet from official algolia examples - https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/blob/master/examples/media/URLSync.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import qs from "qs";

const updateAfter = 700;
const searchStateToURL = (searchState) =>
  searchState ? `${window.location.pathname}?${qs.stringify(searchState)}` : "";

const withURLSync = (TestSearch) =>
  class WithURLSync extends Component {
    state = {
      searchState: qs.parse(window.location.search.slice(1)),
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener("popstate", this.onPopState);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      clearTimeout(this.debouncedSetState);
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", this.onPopState);
    }

    onPopState = ({ state }) =>
      this.setState({
        searchState: state || {},
      });

    onSearchStateChange = (searchState) => {
      clearTimeout(this.debouncedSetState);

      this.debouncedSetState = setTimeout(() => {
        window.history.pushState(
          searchState,
          null,
          searchStateToURL(searchState)
        );
      }, updateAfter);

      this.setState({ searchState });
    };

    render() {
      const { searchState } = this.state;

      return (
        <TestSearch
          {...this.props}
          searchState={searchState}
          onSearchStateChange={this.onSearchStateChange}
          createURL={searchStateToURL}
        />
      );
    }
  };

export default withURLSync;
```

It works with react js, but how can I make this code snippet work with next.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put everything that uses `window` under an `if` statement that checks whether the code is running client side or server side.
For example create a function like this:

```
export const isClient = () => !(typeof window === "undefined");
```

Or just a variable:

```
export const isClient = !(typeof window === "undefined");
```

And in your case you can do like this (using the variable one):

```js
componentDidMount() {
  if(isClient) {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", this.onPopState);
  }
}
```

This way you make sure that whenever your code runs `window` is not `undefined`